# Seeding a random generator with the random header

Tags: c++, random

Is there a way to simply seed a random generator but by using the `<random>` header instead of `rand()` and `srand()`?

I found [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) about it quite abstruse.

I did notice that there is a `seed_sq` entry but I fail to understand it and it lacks example.

Lastly, my search engine only yielded me results on SO about `srand` and `rand`.

Please bear in mind that I'm *"new"* with C++ and generating random numbers in this language seems more complicated than, let's say, in Python.

Comment: Some folk find "abstruse" abstruse:-) Would you mind being more specific? Which random generator are you wanting to use?

Comment: Do you mean something like `std::random_device rd; std::mt19937 gen(rd());`?

Comment: @Bathsheba Indeed. Well I'm not sure, I'm _"new"_ to C++ and read that `srand` and `rand` aren't ideal to generate proper random numbers. Even more about getting a number from a range, which is, I found, quite complicated to do properly when not using the `random` header (skewed results, …)

Comment: Your best bet, in the absence of any other information, is to use the Mersenne Twister generator: part of C++11. But it *critically* depends on your use case.

Comment: @JeromeJ: Well, you need to seed your random engine with _something_. That could be the number of seconds since 1970 (`time()` or `chrono`), a constant number (like `42`) or a non-deterministic number given by your OS/hardware (`random_device`).

Comment: @Zeta Oh? Is it what `gen(rd())` does? If so, now I understand. I only seen this code sample without explanation. If it is, do not hesitate to post it as an answer.

Comment: For MANY cases, using `srand` and `rand` is perfectly adequate. The major downfall is the fact that there is no specification for what RAND_MAX is, or how long the sequence is before it repeats, etc. Sure, mt19937 is probably a "better" random number generator in that it has a long time before it repeats... But there is nothing saying that `rand` can't be a MT19937 implementation! If you just want something to simulate throwing a dice and you're not losing $$$$ if someone can predict the sequence, `rand` is probably good enough.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Very nice to know! I just thought that the C++11 way to do it properly ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/20136256/ ) was simpler than the `rand` one ( http://stackoverflow.com/a/2999130/ ) but then I wondered how to seed the `random` version. I think @Zeta answered my question but I'm waiting for confirmation of my guess.

Comment: @JeromeJ , here is an example for `seed_seq` and random number generation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31090804/1915854

Comment: The example on this page shows how to seed random number generation only using C++11 stuff... http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator()/

But `srand()` and `rand()` are probably fine.  They're certainly easier than using the new methods.